# A way to update one database with many databases with for loop or something like that changing df iloc value [ Python Sqlite]

Tags: python, database, dataframe, sqlite

I have managed to update database with several databases located in specific directory like this:

```
    path2 = r'C://Users//samor//Session//KOPIA BAZ'
    paths = []
    try:

        for file in os.listdir(path2):
            if file.endswith('.db'):

                paths.append(file)
    except:
        print("Ścieżka nie istnieje")
    df = pd.DataFrame(paths)

   print(str(df.iloc[0, 0]))


    db_conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(path2, str(df.iloc[0, 0])))
    c = db_conn.cursor()


    c.executescript("""ATTACH DATABASE 'baza kalkulacji.db' AS other;
                            INSERT INTO other.baza_kalkulacji (Numer_Kalkulacji,Sciezka_Kalkulacji,Opis_Kalkulacji)
                            SELECT Numer_Kalkulacji,Sciezka_Kalkulacji,Opis_Kalkulacji
                            FROM baza_kalkulacji;""")

    db_conn.commit()
    db_conn.close()

    db_conn = sqlite3.connect('baza kalkulacji.db')
    c = db_conn.cursor()


    c.execute("""
    delete from baza_kalkulacji
    where rowid not in (select min(rowid)
                        from baza_kalkulacji
                        group by Numer_Kalkulacji,Sciezka_Kalkulacji,Opis_Kalkulacji) """)

    db_conn.commit()

    db_conn.close()
```

But the problem is...the number of databases will grow in time so i should add copy of the above code hundreds of time while changing value of row in :

db_conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(path2, str(df.iloc[0, 0])))

So the **question** is:

IS there any solution to add this for loop or something that will connect to next and next database that is in that directory and will keep on inserting these tables like i did in code? Like automatically changing that value for a row in df.iloc ????

Comment: There is a hard limit of 10 attached databases, so you'll either need to attach to one database in turn and detach, or change your schema to not require this extra step.

Comment: Okay, i will surely change that in code. I can handle detaching databases. Thank you for that information! Very helpful. Do you know how to handle that df iloc changing value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out like this:

```
   path2 = r'C://Users//samor//Session//KOPIA BAZ'
    paths = []
    try:

        for file in os.listdir(path2):
            if file.endswith('.db'):

                paths.append(file)
    except:
        print("Ścieżka nie istnieje")


    df = pd.DataFrame(paths)

    # print(df)



    # print(str(df.iloc[0, 0]))

    index = df.index
    
    number_of_rows = len(index)

    print(number_of_rows)

    for bazy in range(number_of_rows):
        
        

        db_conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(path2, str(df.iloc[bazy, 0])))
        c = db_conn.cursor()


        c.executescript("""ATTACH DATABASE 'baza kalkulacji.db' AS other;
                                INSERT INTO other.baza_kalkulacji (Numer_Kalkulacji,Sciezka_Kalkulacji,Opis_Kalkulacji)
                                SELECT Numer_Kalkulacji,Sciezka_Kalkulacji,Opis_Kalkulacji
                                FROM baza_kalkulacji;""")

        c.execute("DETACH DATABASE 'other'")

        db_conn.commit()
        db_conn.close()

        db_conn = sqlite3.connect('baza kalkulacji.db')
        c = db_conn.cursor()

        c.execute("""
        delete from baza_kalkulacji
        where rowid not in (select max(rowid)
                             from baza_kalkulacji
                             group by Numer_Kalkulacji) """)

        db_conn.commit()

        db_conn.close()
```